# Include cover letter when it is not required?

Tags: paper-submission

I am considering a paper submission to a journal. In the submission platform, it is possible to upload a cover letter but it is not required. (In the past, I 've submitted to other journals where the cover letter was mandatory.)

Are there any good reasons to add a cover letter when it is not required, yet possible to upload in the submission platform? For instance, does it seem unprofessional to not include a cover letter even if it is not required?

Comment: Related if not duplicate: [What is the point of a cover letter in journal submission?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/96298/7734)

Comment: *For instance, does it seem unprofessional to not include a cover letter even if it is not required?* – I would rather consider it unprofessional if you waste my time with some boilerplate document which is entirely redundant to the data collected via the submission forms. Problem is you usually cannot divine in which camp the editor belongs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have something important to say to the editor, then include a cover, otherwise it is just noise. In particular, don't use it to try to "boost" your work.

But if you can help the editor find suitable reviewers by, for example, situating your work in the larger framework then do so. I'm not suggesting you recommend reviewers unless asked, however.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are plenty of good reasons to include a cover letter: the cover letter is how you communicate with the editor.

Comment: Assuming you have something worth saying, of course.

Comment: … and there is no form for “other information for the editors” or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, because, in the letter, you can specify those missing details in the submission form, which can help the editor with the publication of the article. And just writing a note on the fact about nothing makes sense.